# Access INSERT query with 150+ parameters and a data mismatch. How to find which param is wrong?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm reading a tab delimited text file into a `String[]`. Then, go thru the array line by line, split it into individual elements (`currentLine.Split('\t')`), make changes to the elements as needed, and then do a `Parameters.Add` to add each element as a parameter to the query string.

For the most part, it works and has added stuff to the Access table. However, it hit something in the data that it didn't like, and I'm having trouble determining which element is causing the data mismatch. The only error I'm getting (VS Express 2012) is `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`.

Is there a way to see which parameter is causing the error? I can tell which line it is by looking at what's already been added to the table, but I don't see where the problem is.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: First problem - you trying to create your own csv parser. [Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser!](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems pretty general although here are some techniques that will help you resolve it:

1. Wrap your database insert/update statement in a try / catch. Within the catch block write the parameters that were active at time of the insert.
2. Inspect the exception for an inner exception that will likely have more specific details of the invalid parameter/value.

Comment: thanks .. i was looking more for techniques than actual lines of code.